# System Center: Agent Proxy

Tags: monitoring, operating-system, system-center, mom

```
Specific Error: Agent proxying needs to be enabled for a health service to submit discovery data about other computers.

Microsoft.SystemCenter.DiscoveryWriteActionModule.AgentProxyingNotEnabled.Alert
```

We use Microsoft System Center 2007.  The management server throws this error. I have enabled proxying per the instructions but alas the error re-occurs.  Has anyone else had this and fixed it? or do I just disable the monitor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following that alert you should get a specific ID for the managed object. Run this query in SQL server against the OperationsManager database:

select * from basemanagedentity 
where basemanagedentityid = 'IDGOESHERE'

and then check the Path column. It will list one of your servers. Make sure Agent Proxying is enabled for that specific health service/server.

1. In the SCE console, click 'Administration'.
2. Click 'Agent Managed'
3. Double-click the above listed server. (Or right-click and select properties.)
4. In security tab, choose "Allow this agent to act as a proxy and discover managed objects on other computers"

Comment: I had performed the above, however in the DB it did not exist...I flipped the bit manualy and all is good now. Thanks for the lead!